# Get results from 2 table where id doesn't equal 1

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables "**Request**" and "**Profiles**". I wanted to query both the tables and get the results from **profiles** where values is **NOT EQUAL** to "**1**" on column **request_req1** and **request_req2** on request table.

**Request**

[image]

**Profiles**

[image]

**Currently The MySQL Query am working with**

```
SELECT 
    profiles.profile_id, 
    profiles.profile_pub_key, 
    profiles.profile_photo, 
    profiles.profile_username, 
    profiles.profile_name, 
    requests.request_req1, 
    requests.request_req2
FROM 
    PROFILES 
INNER JOIN 
    requests ON requests.request_req1 <> 1
INNER JOIN 
    requests ON requests.request_req2 <> 1
WHERE 
    profiles.profile_id <> 1 
ORDER BY 
    RAND() 
LIMIT 2
```

The above query returns MySQL Syntax error. Please help, what am I doing wrong here.

Comment: How are the tables linked?

Comment: @juergend using "request_req1" and "request_req2"

Comment: What's the common field between profiles and requests that you want them to join on? i.e. how requests and profiles related?

Comment: @almasshaikh the common fields are "request_req1" and "request_req2"

Comment: do you see these fields in profiles table @RedVirus?

Comment: @almasshaikh Yes I do.

Comment: @RedVirus: Then why do they not appear in the columns you show for `profiles`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try if it works for you:

```
   SELECT 
        P.profile_id, 
        P.profile_pub_key, 
        P.profile_photo, 
        P.profile_username, 
        P.profile_name, 
        R.request_req1, 
        R.request_req2
    FROM 
        PROFILES P
    INNER JOIN 
        requests R
    ON (R.request_req1 <> 1 AND R.request_req2 <> 1)
    WHERE P.profile_id <> 1 
    ORDER BY RAND() 
    LIMIT 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this query:

```
SELECT 
profiles.profile_id, 
profiles.profile_pub_key, 
profiles.profile_photo, 
profiles.profile_username, 
profiles.profile_name, 
requests.request_req1, 
requests.request_req2
FROM 
    PROFILES 
    INNER JOIN 
    requests 
    ON  requests.request_req1 = PROFILES.request_req1
    AND requests.request_req2 = PROFILES.request_req2
WHERE profiles.profile_id <> 1 
AND   requests.request_req2 <> 1
AND   requests.request_req1 <> 1
ORDER BY RAND() 
LIMIT 2
```